# Fail in working with a Eigen function

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

The purpose of the mentioned part of my code is solving a linear equation Ax=b for "A" as a  square matrix and "b" as a vector with the same size:

The problem is, I get fail in compiling when I try to use the function of the Eigen in my function:

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"
using namespace Eigen;

void StreamTemperature::avgTemperature() {

TotalDist = pm->get_total_dist();
vector<vector<double>> A(TotalDist, std::vector<double>(TotalDist));
vector<double> b_copy;
VectorXd x_eigen;                               //Eigen format! 
MatrixXd A_eigen(TotalDist, TotalDist);
VectorXd b_eigen(TotalDist);

for (int i = 0; i < (TotalDist - 1); i++) {
    A[i + 1][i] = 1.0;
    A[i][i] = 5.0;
    A[i][i + 1] = -1.0;
}
A[TotalDist - 1][TotalDist - 1] = b[TotalDist - 1][j] + c[TotalDist - 1][j];
b_copy.resize(TotalDist);
    for (int i = 0; i < TotalDist; i++) { b_copy[i] = 10.0; }

    for (int i = 0; i < TotalDist; i++)
    A_eigen.row(i) = Map<VectorXd>(A[i].data(), TotalTime);
    for (int i = 0; i < TotalDist; i++)
    b_eigen(i) = b_copy[i];
    x_eigen = A_eigen.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b_eigen);

    for (int i = 0; i < TotalDist; i++) {
        x[i] = x_eigen(i);
    }

}
```

The Eigen related part work well in anohter project but I have problem here! 
Here is the compiling error:

```
1>e:\suny-files\spring2017\summer2017\runforsyracusemin\itreecoolnewsw\eigen\src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h(659): error C2338: FLOATING_POINT_ARGUMENT_PASSED__INTEGER_WAS_EXPECTED
1>e:\suny-files\spring2017\summer2017\runforsyracusemin\itreecoolnewsw\eigen\src/Core/Matrix.h(250): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>>::_init2<T0,T1>(int,int,double *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T0=double,
1>            T1=double
1>        ]
```

Any thoughts?! :|

Comment: Can you add your compile error? Also, try to make your code more self-contained such that others can reproduce your error. See [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What's the error message and to which line does it refer?

Comment: @bjhend I tried to edit the code and make it more readable, I also added the compiling error

Comment: When declaring A_eigen , Try to explicitly cast TotalDist to int. The compilation error shows you are passing floating point number where an into is expected.

Comment: @AdityaG it worked!! :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring A_eigen , Try to explicitly cast TotalDist to int. The compilation error shows you are passing floating point number where an into is expected.

Also check the value of the TotalDist and the dimension of A_eigen .